# Access data in Google App Script from spread sheet modal html form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google spreadsheet script which will show modal dialog using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog` using a html form which is created as a file in the SpreadSheet Script project.

This is how my Google Script project structure is :

```
--Code.gs
 |
 |- openFormModalDialog()
 |- fetchData()
 |- updateSheet()
 |
--form.html
```

When click button in my form.html which is showed in the modal from the Code.gs I wan to call a function in my Code.gs to process the data entered by the user in the form. I have multiple input fields in the form.

I want to access form input values to make external service call and fetch and updated sheet rows.

I am not able to figure out how to access the data in the form filed in App Script.

This is how I am opening my form:

```
function openFormModalDialog() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
     .setWidth(400)
     .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'User Information');
}
```

Is there a way I can pass my App-Script function as parameter to html? I am not able to find any relevant document related to this.

Comment: As of now I have added multiple `prompt` to take input from user to use in the app script.

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if you need explanations

Comment: The documentation for the method you use explicitly states how you can communicate with Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the google.script.run api

Example :

```html
<button onClick = "google.script.run.test();">Click me to run test()</button>
```

This will run your `test()`

Check this out  : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)

We can **pass arguments** to function like this `google.script.run.test("value1");`

We can **run another function**(javascript function in web page/dialog here) **after this function has completed execution**, like this `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nextFunctionName).test("value1");`

We can also **run another function**(javascript function in web page/dialog here) **if this function fails its execution**, like this `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(nextFunctionName).test("value1");`